# Clustering based on spectral variations using SNIC (Simple Non-Iterative Clustering) - GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, clustering, google-earth-engine-python-api, google-colab

SNIC (Simple Non-Iterative Clustering) outputs a band of cluster IDs and per-cluster averages for each of the input bands [snic](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-algorithms-image-segmentation-snic).

I am trying to generate clusters based on spectral variation using SNIC. I have generated the clusters using SNIC but they seem a bit meaningless as there is no information on why those clusters were made and if for example there are pixels with similar properties farther away then they weren't clustered into one particular cluster. I have tried to increase the size of the `neighborhoodSize` to 8000 to see if it can cluster similar pixels located farther away into one cluster but it is taking forever to render the map on Google-Colab.
That is why, now I am thinking if there could be anyway to use spectral properties for clustering, maybe it will make some sense!

**Code:**

```
seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(64)
snic = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC(
image = img, 
size =  32,
compactness = 5,
connectivity =  8,
neighborhoodSize = 256,
seeds =  seeds
)
```

**Question**:
Is there any way to generate clusters based on spectral variation using SNIC algorithm?